# VBA Loop Through Columns

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a macro that will select the column with "Est #" in the first row and paste the entire column in a new column.

I know how to loop through rows:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    If Range("C" & i) = "All values USD Millions." Then
        Range("C" & i & ":H" & i).Delete
    Else
        Range("A3").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that columns have letters, not numbers, so I am unsure how I can loop through the first 30 columns and paste the column with "Est #" in the first row into Range("CA:CA").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it thus, although Find is more efficient

```
Sub test()

Dim c As Long

For c = 1 To 30
    If Cells(1, c).Value = "Est #" Then
        Cells(1, c).EntireColumn.Copy Cells(1, "CA")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Here is the Find method

```
Sub test()

Dim rFind As Range

Set rFind = Range("A1").Resize(, 30).Find(What:="Est #", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
    rFind.EntireColumn.Copy Cells(1, "CA")
End If

End Sub
```