# How to merge adjacent cells in the same row VBA when the value is the same?

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'm a beginner with VBA on excel so I'm in need of help.

I've got to merge adjacent cells that are in the same column, being the range variable, since it'll always change.

The following image shows what I'd like do achieve:

[image]

Comment: What you need is a [loop over your columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073482/8769365) to [merge all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369913/8769365) that [are equal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-Statements). Where exactly lies your problem?

Comment: I would recommend *not* merging, but using alignment... in VBA, you could use .HorizontalAlignment = "xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection" which (as written) centers across a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it was suggested, you need to loop trough out the columns, and determine the range between the repeated cells in order to merge them.

Use something like this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeCells()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim rng As Range
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim ColumnsInRange As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

'Last Column Used
LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Rows
For r = 3 To 4

'Columns
For c = 1 To LastColumn

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c + 1)
ColumnsInRange = ColumnsInRange + 1
c = c + 1
Loop

Set rng = Range(Cells(r, c - ColumnsInRange), Cells(r, c))
rng.Select
With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge

    ColumnsInRange = 0

Next c

Next r

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! It's exactly what I need!